# Linker error with variable templates

Tags: c++, templates, linker, c++14, template-variables

Consider the code below:

```
#include <iostream>

template<typename T>
T n;

int main()
{
    n<int> = 42;
    std::cout << n<int> << std::endl;
}
```

It [compiles and links with g++5.1](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/StNdWNQSYnIsSGsT), and it displays `42`. However, clang++ [fails to link it](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/1zZoXZQ7tg2G9qMF):

> undefined reference to n<int>

If I initialize the template variable like

```
template<typename T> T n{};
```

then [clang++ links it too](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/KNnn2CuuNjEf6Wk1).

Any idea what's going on? Is clang++ "correct" in failing to link the program? And why does it work if I initialize the template variable?

As far as I know, template variables are just syntactic sugar for template wrappers around static members, so `n<int> = 42` is effectively specializing the `int` instance. IMO, the code should link.

Comment: Looks like https://llvm.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=22825

Comment: @dyp I agree, that looks like the problem.

Comment: That's the one indeed. @dyp post an _answer_ not a comment!!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a bug in clang++ [#22825](https://llvm.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=22825). The bug report has been filed on 2015-03-06 and the bug has not yet been fixed. Richard Smith supposes this definition is incorrectly treated only as a forward-declaration.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't have any more information on this bug. I might have some time later to look into the clang sources.